# How to get name and id from 2 tables where name from 1 table matches with another name in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2)

Table 1 contains

```
Description                                    Code
HOLD  PINS                                      1
PAHARPUR SERIES COOLING TOWER,65CMH OF WATER    2
KSB  MAKE  CENTRIFUGAL PUMP,TYPE MEGA GC65-200  3
```

Table 2 contains

```
Item_Code      Description          Category     
abc             hold pins            cat 1
aaa             PAHARPUR SERIES      cat2
bbb             KSB  MAKE            cat3
```

I want to see if description from table 2 has the value in description in table 1, if yes then list that along with item code.

Result should be like

```
item_code      Description
abc            HOLD  PINS
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Where is your code?

Comment: I tried left outer join SELECT item_code,ItemDescription FROM table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.Description=table1.Description  , actually the description in table 2 may be equal or it contains some words from table1. so not getting as expected.

Comment: Use SQL JOIN. 

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: thank you i will have a look

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work fine

```
select item_code ,description from table2
where description in (select description from table1);
```

'''
it is the nested query